# add rel="nofollow" to comment_metadata

Tags: php, wordpress

how can i add rel="nofollow" to link that have time tag, inside the comment-metadata div?

```
<div class="comment-metadata">
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/hello-world/#comment-2">
<time datetime="2013-12-22T10:43:03+00:00">...</time>
</a>
</div>


  function add_nofollow_to_comment_metadata( $link ) {
      return str_replace( '")\'>', '")\' rel=\'nofollow\'>', $link );
  }

  add_filter( 'comment_comment_metadata', 'add_nofollow_to_comment_metadata' );
```

i use `<?php wp_list_comments(); ?>` without any customise.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to modify this behavior via hooks or filters. But you can implement this by:

1. Using [get_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) function. It allows maximum customization.
2. Extending `Walker_Comment` class and implementing your custom functionality.

The first option is obviously simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add code
WordPress will automatically nofollow comment links

Comment: if wordpress do that why i'm asking this question? :)